# WiFi is not working in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, wifi-direct

I want to connect to WiFi but there is no option for it in the network settings, though I am able to see the bluetooth option under wireless network.
What should I do?
Tell me if some patch is missing or am I somewhere wrong in connecting to WiFi.

Comment: Could you tell what wireless adaptor are you using?

Comment: Ralink RT5390 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter.. its an HP 2000 notebook laptop.

Comment: Is there a problem in adapter??

Answer (score 0):

Go to Software Sources and choose extra drivers. Try to activate one, if available. Maybe, you will need an internet connection with a cable to activate the driver.

Comment: I didnt find any driver in 'additional drivers'..

Comment: There is no extra drivers..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install [jockey](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nl/lucid/jockey-gtk) (Additional drivers) from the software center (cable connection required) and choose there for an driver (if available).

If you want to install it from command line: `sudo apt-get install jockey-kde`. To run type `sudo jockey-kde`.